# How to set the label of a QVBox to it's minimum size?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am currently developing a chat application in order to be familiar with the pyqt5 framework. Still I am not that familiar with layouts. I tried to stack up recieved messages in a scrollable area after putting them into a label. But if there is one message, it occupies all the space from the scroll area. This is how it looks like.
[image: srl1]

I want it to take the minimum size it can take irrespective of number of labels in scroll area. Like this.

[image: srl2]]

How can I do that? This is the code.

```
def __init__(self):  #constructor of main application
    ###
    ####

    self.scrollwid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.scrollareavbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.scrollwid.setLayout(self.scrollareavbox)
    self.screen3.s3.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollwid)  #THE SCROLL AREA IS IN SCREEN3 NAMED scrollArea
    self.screen3.s3.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.screen3.s3.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    ###

    def messageUpdateSlot(self, message):  #WHERE I STACK LABELS
        #create a new Qlabel and put that in the stacked widget.
        lbl_instance = self.createLabel(message)
        lbl_instance.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid black; background-color: yellow")
        self.scrollareavbox.addWidget(lbl_instance)
        
    def createLabel(self, text):  #WHERE I CREATE LABEL FOR EACH MESSAGE RECIEVED
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label.setText(text)
        #label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8(objName))
        return label
```

Comment: `self.scrollareavbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)`.

Comment: Alternatively, `self.scrollareavbox.addStretch()` in the init, and in `messageUpdateSlot` do `self.scrollareavbox.insertWidget(self.scrollareavbox.count() - 1, lbl_instance)`

Comment: Both methods worked. Thanks for your help.